# How to call methods in a different class

Tags: python, oop

Confused on OOP in Python3:

main.py:

```
import ma as m1

r = m1.ma1() 
r.doit()
print(r.m1avar)
print(r.m2var)
r.m2do()
```

ma.py:

```
import mb as m2

class ma1(m2.mclass2):
    
    m1avar = 10
    
    def doit(self):
        self.logout("doit!")
        
    def logout(self, a):
        print(a+" <--- this is correct")
```

mb.py:

```
class mclass2():
    
    m2var = 5;
    m1avar = 5;
    
    def doit(self):
        super().logout("m2 do it")
    
    def m2do(self):
        super().logout("child class")
```

Produces:

```
doit! <--- this is correct
10
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/rrr/m1.py", line 8, in <module>
    r.m2do()
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/rrr/mb.py", line 11, in m2do
    super().logout("child class")
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'logout'
```

How do I get the lowest class (mclass2) to access methods in a higher class ma1 - specifically the .logout method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - mclass2 does not see it's parent class as super, just as itself. So it's `self.` that you need not `super.`

```
class mclass2():
    
    m2var = 5;
    m1avar = 5;
    
    def doit(self):
        super().logout("m2 do it")
    
    def m2do(self):
        self.logout("child class")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that m2 doesnt inherit from m1. In other words, m2 doesn't even know that m1 exist.

The only thing you can do to make it work is assign a m1 object at an instance of the m2 object. I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).